is orthogonal complement of a subspace contained in another decomposition of Hilbert space
Let $H$ be a (infinite dimensional) Hilbert space and $v\in H$ be a nonzero vector. Define $V$ to be the span of $v$. It is given that $V+A=H$ where $A$ is a closed subspace of $H$. I am trying to find out the relation between the orthogonal complement of $V$ and $A$. I believe $V^{\perp}\subset A$.
Here is what I am thinking. Let $q$ be the quotient map of $H$ by mod out $V$. Then $V^{\perp}$ is isomorphic to $H/V$. Now assume $q(A)\neq H/V$, then $q^{-1}(q(A))=V+A\neq H$, which is a contradiction. So $q(A)=H/V$. So $V^{\perp}\subset A$.
Does the proof work?

The claim does not hold. Take any $w$ linearly independent with $v$ and $ w \not\perp v.$ Let  $B={v,w}^\perp.$ For $A=B+w$ we have $H=A+V$ and $V^\perp\not\subset A.$ Indeed the element $w'=w-\langle w,v\rangle v.$ Then $w'\in V^\perp $ and $w'\not\in A.$ WLOG I assume $v$ is a unlt vector.

$q(A)=H/V$ is true but does not imply $V^{\perp}\subset A$.
